# Cypress - AEM default Captcha Service

Tags: javascript, forms, automated-tests, cypress, aem

How can I submit the default AEM (Adobe Experience Manager) captcha for testing purposes? Currently AEM allows to add 2 kinds of captcha: the first is **default AEM built-in captcha service** and the second is **google reCaptcha service**. In the second case it is so easy to write tests because google provides a test key that allows to submit a captcha whenever you want. But I dont have a clue how can I handle the first case. I haven't found any good simple solution to deal with this. Any ideas, workarounds?

Documentation:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/forms/adaptive-forms/forms-captcha-feature-video-use.html?lang=en